# Change WooCommerce backorder message (product page) based on product category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Im trying to create various different custom backorder messages based on product category for specific products. e.g.

If product is under category X and on backorder display custom backorder message X on product page.
If product is under category Y and on backorder display custom backorder message Y on product page.
If product is under category Z and on backorder display custom backorder message Z on product page.

I know you can normally hook into filter:

```
woocommerce_get_availability_text
```

and do something like below. But this applies to all backorders. Anyone know how i'd go about doing category specific?

```
function custom_backorder_message( $text, $product ){
  if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
  $text = __( 'Please allow 28 days for delivery of this item' );
}
return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_backorder_message', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add follows code snippet -

```
function custom_backorder_message( $text, $product ){
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        // Dont forget to replace x,y,z with respective categories
        if( has_term( 'x', 'product_cat' ) ) {
            $text = __( 'Please allow 28 days for delivery of this item', 'text-domain' );
        }elseif(has_term( 'y', 'product_cat' ) ){
            $text = __( 'Your Y category product message goes here', 'text-domain' );
        }elseif(has_term( 'z', 'product_cat' ) ){
            $text = __( 'Your Z category product message goes here', 'text-domain' );
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_backorder_message', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Perfect don't know why i didn't think of using if( has_term( 'x', 'product_cat' ) ) {