# Custom backorder status message based on WooCommerce taxonomy terms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible that this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57919828/change-woocommerce-backorder-message-product-page-based-on-product-category?newreg=6e14406a91134f44a0e050f37522b8dd) doesn't work anymore since WooCommerce 6.5?

I was reading through the WooCommerce documentation to find a solution.
I have this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function custom_get_availability_text( $text, $product, $product_cat ) {
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) && $product->get_stock_quantity() === 0 ) {
        if(has_term( '2 à 5 werkdagen', $product->tags ) ) {
            $text = __( '<p><span style="color: #99cc00;"><strong>Geschatte levertijd: 2 à 5 werkdagen</strong></span></p>' );
        } elseif( has_term( '1 à 2 weken', $product->tags ) ) {
            $text =  __( '<p><span style="color: #99cc00;"><strong>Geschatte levertijd: 1 à 2 weken</strong></span></p>' );
        } elseif(has_term( '2 à 3 weken', $product->tags ) ) {
            $text =  __( '<p><span style="color: #99cc00;"><strong>Geschatte levertijd: 2 à 3 weken</strong></span></p>' );
        } elseif(has_term( 'Abonnementen', $product_cat ) || has_term( 'Abonnementen', $product->tags ) ) {
            $text =  __( '<p><strong>Doorlopende betalingsopdracht</strong></p>' );
        } 
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_availability_text', 'custom_get_availability_text', 10, 3 );
```

I tried to adjust the code with new information from the documentation.
Removed the `$text` argument and used `return` but to no avail.